# Integrating UrbanAirship

Tags: cordova, urbanairship.com

I am trying to integrate urban airship push notifications into my phonegap iOS app.  I've followed  the [instructions](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Client:+PhoneGap:+iOS+Plugin) but I keep getting "lexical or preprocessor issue 'UAGlobal.h' file not found" when I build the project.

I have found [this](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/450206-lexical-or-preprocessor-issue-uaglobal-h-file-not-found-phonegap-cordova-2-urban-airship) but the fix doesn't help.  I feel my problem may lie with the header search paths but I'm not entirely sure.  Has anyone had similar trouble?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem as well, and after a lot of research I was able to get it working.  I was only getting the error when I was trying to archive the app for adhoc testing.  From what I can recall, I had to add additional entries into the Header search paths.  Here are my header search paths.  There are 4 entries I added based on an article I found online.  Can't remember where it was though.

```
$(SRCROOT)/Airship
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)
```

Make sure these are on separate lines in the popup box where you add them, and the check boxes are checked for each.

I added these to both the Debug and Release search paths and then it worked.  Make sure you are adding them under Targets.  When you click on the main Project in the file tree on the left, you then click on the app name under Targets, then go to Build Settings.  That was where I added them.  I think that was all I did to get it working.

If that doesn't work, I will need to remember what else I did.

Comment: +1 for great advice but unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. I'm seriously confused by this.  I've seen loads of articles, forum and blog posts on this but nobody seems to be able to nail down what the problem actually is.

Comment: I looked again at the post you linked in your question.  I tried to add both UA libraries to my project, but that didn't work for me.  I am only linking libUAirshipPush-1.3.2.a in my Build Phases and in my Frameworks folder.

Comment: Also, I edited the post really quick for formatting and added more info.  When you add these to the search paths, make sure they are all on separate lines in the little popup box.  When I first added them, they weren't on separate lines, but as soon as I fixed them it worked.